# Como puedo responder comentarios que contengan una palabra clave?

Tags: facebook-api, facebook-graph-api

Quiero responder o enviar mensaje a comentarios de grupos de acuerdo a los comentarios que contengan una palabra clave, con la API de Facebook

Alguien sabe como hacerlo

Comment: Una publicación que simplemente dice: "este es mi ejercicio, resuélvanlo", no es bien recibida. Es mejor que incluyas el contexto (usa el botón [edit] para hacer cambios en tu pregunta): incluye que intentaste/investigaste y también cual es el problema puntual que tuviste. Demuestra algo que nos indique que formas parte de la experiencia de aprender a solucionar tu problema.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!